# In pygtk, how can I combine font selection and color selection dialogs in one dialog?

Tags: python, pygtk

I'm using pygtk and searches for the best way to combine font and color dialogs in one, which is the most pythonic way to do it ?

Answer (score 2):

You must change the 'base' and 'text' parts of the widget's style. You can also edit the 'foreground' property. Some useful shorthand methods to change those style properties inherited from gtk.Widget are:

```
widget.modify_fg(state, color)
widget.modify_bg(state, color)
widget.modify_base(state, color)
widget.modify_text(state, color)
```

Windowless widgets such as gtk.Label, gtk.Button, gtk.Paned, gtk.Frame, etc, (see FAQ 3.5) despite inheriting from gtk.Widget don't allow changing its background and base color as those properties don't exist for them. If you want to get them you need to insert the widget inside a gtk.EventBox which adds this properties. Example:

```
import gtk

window = gtk.Window(gtk.WINDOW_TOPLEVEL)
window.connect("destroy", gtk.mainquit)

label = gtk.Label("one, two, testing...")
eb = gtk.EventBox()
eb.add(label)
eb.modify_bg(gtk.STATE_NORMAL, gtk.gdk.color_parse("blue"))
window.add(eb)

window.show_all()
gtk.main()
```

Also suggest you read this [gtk.gdk.Window — on-screen display areas in the target window system.](http://www.pygtk.org/docs/pygtk/class-gdkwindow.html#method-gdkwindow--set-background)

By the other hand, the pygtk have dialogs for the change the colors and change or select fonts.

Example 1 : **Change fonts**

```
import gtk
import pango
class PyApp(gtk.Window): 
    def __init__(self):
        gtk.Window.__init__(self)
        self.set_size_request(300, 150)
        self.set_position(gtk.WIN_POS_CENTER)
        self.connect("destroy", gtk.main_quit)
        self.set_title("Font Selection Dialog")


        self.label = gtk.Label("The only victory over love is flight.")
        button = gtk.Button("Select font")
        button.connect("clicked", self.on_clicked)

        fix = gtk.Fixed()
        fix.put(button, 100, 30)
        fix.put(self.label, 30, 90)
        self.add(fix)

        self.show_all()

    def on_clicked(self, widget):
        fdia = gtk.FontSelectionDialog("Select font name")
        response = fdia.run()

        if response == gtk.RESPONSE_OK:
            font_desc = pango.FontDescription(fdia.get_font_name())
            if font_desc:
                self.label.modify_font(font_desc)

        fdia.destroy()
PyApp()
gtk.main()
```

Example 2:**Change the color of label**

```
 import gtk
class PyApp(gtk.Window): 
    def __init__(self):
        super(PyApp, self).__init__()

        self.set_size_request(300, 150)
        self.set_position(gtk.WIN_POS_CENTER)
        self.connect("destroy", gtk.main_quit)
        self.set_title("Color Selection Dialog")


        self.label = gtk.Label("The only victory over love is flight.")
        button = gtk.Button("Select color")
        button.connect("clicked", self.on_clicked)

        fix = gtk.Fixed()
        fix.put(button, 100, 30)
        fix.put(self.label, 30, 90)
        self.add(fix)

        self.show_all()

    def on_clicked(self, widget):
        cdia = gtk.ColorSelectionDialog("Select color")
        response = cdia.run()

        if response == gtk.RESPONSE_OK:
            colorsel = cdia.colorsel
            color = colorsel.get_current_color()
            self.label.modify_fg(gtk.STATE_NORMAL, color)

        cdia.destroy()
PyApp()
gtk.main()
```

Hope it can helps.